# Why is SQL Server injection not working in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Login password injection is not working - how to implement in my project?

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-G9SO8KA;Initial Catalog=coolege;Integrated Security=True");
    string qry="select * from tblstudent where Email='"+Login1.UserName+"'and Password='"+Login1.Password+"' ";
    adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(qry,con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adpt.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
    {
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a badly worded question. Please provide some more information. How is it not working? What are you trying, What error messages are you getting

Comment: Please say this isn't production code, it's massively vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), please use the `SqlCommand` with parameters. Else this [obligatory XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) will happen to you

Comment: What do you mean by password injection ? Do you mean **dependency injection** ? Side note, use parameters in your query, otherwise, your code is open to SQL Injection !

Comment: This is not ASP.NET MVC 5, it's WebForms. Also: sql injection == troubles, use parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Don't use concatenate strings on your sql query. Use SQL parameters
2. You are not opening the connection

Try like:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-G9SO8KA;Initial Catalog=coolege;Integrated Security=True");
string qry="select * from tblstudent where Email='@name and Password=@pass";
adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(qry,con);
adpt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Login1.UserName;
adpt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Login1.Password;
con.Open();
...
```